# Approximating a functions area in an interval

Tags: python

I am trying to approximate an area for a function f within an interval [a, b] using N + 1 equally spaced points.

a and b should be inputted with type int or float, N should be input with type int, and f should be input as a lambda function implemented so that it can be applied to numpy arrays.

This is what I have so far, how could I go about fixing it?

```
import numpy as np # Importing necessary libraries

def area_approximator(a = 0, b = 1, N = 1, f = lambda x: 0):
        
    x_values = np.linspace(a, b, N+1) # Generate N+1 equidistant points between a and b
    
    dx = (b - a) / N # Calculate the width of each subinterval
    
    area = 0 # Initialize the area variable
    
    # Iterate over each subinterval
    for i in range(N):
        # Calculate the midpoint of the subinterval
        x_mid = (x_values[i] + x_values[i+1]) / 2
        
        # Calculate the function value at the midpoint
        f_mid = f(x_mid)
        
        # Add the area of the rectangle (width * height) to the total area
        area += dx * f_mid
    
    return area

# Prompt the user to input values for a, b, N, and f
a_input = float(input("Enter the value of a: "))
b_input = float(input("Enter the value of b: "))
N_input = int(input("Enter the value of N: "))
f_input = input("Enter the function f(x): ")

# Convert the input string to a lambda function
f = eval(f_input)

# Call the area_approximator function with user inputs
result = area_approximator(a=a_input, b=b_input, N=N_input, f=f)
print(result)
```